# SQL Server: show string majority

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, group

I am looking to make a query in SQL SERVER that will allow me to display in a grouping the string that appears in most cases. Not the amount, not the maximum, but the string that is displayed in most cases:

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | ccc |
| A | 20 | aaa |
| A | 35 | bbb |
| A | 25 | aaa |
| A | 10 | aaa |
| B | 15 | ccc |
| B | 15 | bbb |
| B | 30 | bbb |

Select sum(colB) as total, ***?????????*** as lable
from table1
Group BY colA

Resukt:

| colA | total | lable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | aaa |
| B | 60 | bbb |

thanks!

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to calculate a `ROW_NUMBER` or a `DENSE_RANK` on the COUNT of records per ColA & ColC.

A `DENSE_RANK = 1` could show more than 1 top if there's a tie.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   ColA
> , TotalColB AS Total
> , ColC AS Lable
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT ColA, ColC
>   , TotalColB = SUM(SUM(ColB)) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA)
>   , Rnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
>   FROM YourTable 
>   GROUP BY ColA, ColC
> ) q
> WHERE Rnk = 1
> ORDER BY ColA;
> ```

> | ColA | Total | Lable |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 100 | aaa |
> | B | 60 | bbb |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f6a927d86db0da07d1348974f73b595)*

Comment: Nice. I always forget you can use aggs inside dense_rank.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it

```
select t.ColA,
       sum(t.total) as ColB,
       max(s2.ColC)
from   ( select s.ColA,
                s.ColC,
                sum(ColB) as total,
                count(1) as numbers
         from   strings s
         group by s.ColA, s.ColC
       ) t  
  outer apply ( select top 1 
                       s.ColA,
                       s.ColC,
                       sum(ColB) as total,
                       count(1) as numbers
                from   strings s
                where  s.ColA = t.ColA 
                group by s.ColA, s.ColC
                order by 4 desc
            ) s2
group by t.ColA
```

Try it in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94a28442d54c864f84344f7dea601539)

Comment: Note this scans `strings` twice.